# Average speed problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

"I take a journey and, due to heavy traffic, crawl along the first half of the complete distance of my journey at an average speed of $10$ mph. How fast would I have to travel over the second half of the journey to bring my average speed to $20$ mph?"

At work, this has been a topic of a long debate.
Proposed answers included:
{infinity, $0, 15, 30, 45$, speed of light~}.

What do you think?

Comment: Take the distance as 10.  Then total distance to travel is 20. What should be the speed the average ?  You have already used up an hour. Can you take it from here ?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Lets say it's a 20 mile journey for example and you travel the first half, 10 mile, in 1 hour.  How many more miles have you got to go and how much time have you got to do it in?

Comment: @Shailesh based on the way the problem is defined, I believe, the distance does not play a significant role. Say, there are two parts to the distance (2d, where 'd' is for distance). During the first part of my journey I do 10 mph (d/10) and during the second part of my journey I must get my average speed to 20 mph (d/x). That yields following formulation: 2d / ((d/10)+(d/x) which, when used, yields an answer speed of light~. However, there is a degree of disagreement among collegues :P

Comment: E.Doroskevic The actual distance is irrelevant @Shailesh and I just picked 20 mile as an example point travelling half the journey at half the speed you have to travel the second half the journey in zero time which is not possible.

Comment: My dear old Dad asked me an equivalent question when I was much younger and the family was on a road trip. As I didn't see the light right away (mumbling something, while sounding a bit skeptical, could be thought of as leading up to taking the average of the speeds on two partial journeys), he made the penny drop with the following gedankenexperiment: "Assume that you travel there at the speed 80 km/h, but come back at the speed 0 km/h. What's your average speed?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x$ be the whole distance. The time to complete the journey is

$$t=\frac{x/2}{v_1}+\frac{x/2}{v_2}$$

The average speed over the whole journey is then

$$v=\frac{x}{t}=\frac{2}{1/v_1+1/v_2}=\frac{2v_1v_2}{v_1+v_2}$$
You want $v=2v_1$, which would mean $v_2/(v_1+v_2)$ would have to be $1$. That means $v_2$ would have to be infinite, as the denominator is always bigger than the numerator.

Another, intuitive way of looking at this: by going twice too slow over half the distance, you spent the entire available time getting half way: you missed your meeting already, no way of getting there in time.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t$ hours the time spent in the first half of the distance, namely $d$ miles, it is known that $$d/2=10t$$
The time needed in order to travel the remaining half of distance, with a speed $v$, is $t_2=(d/2)/v$ and must satisfy
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{\frac{d}{20}+\frac{d}{2v}}&=20\\
\frac{20vd}{vd+10d}&=20\\
\frac{v}{v+10}&=1
\end{align*}